# `Undefined Method` for a has_many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

Why would this not be working?

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :notes, :class_name => "CustomerNote", :foreign_key => 'customer_id'

    def self.called_this_month
        self.notes.where(:date => Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month).count
    end
end
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `notes` for #<Class:0x00000004b37190>
```

Note Model:

```
class CustomerNote < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "customer_contact"

  belongs_to :customer
end
```

Comment: Updated the original post

Comment: Should this: `self.called_this_month` really be this: `called_this_month`

Comment: Doing so renders this error: `undefined method 'called_this_month'`

Comment: `notes` is going to be on an instance of Customer where you're defining called_this_month on the Customer class itself

Answer (score 0):

You can't called `self.notes` in a class method as it read as `Customer.notes` where as you want 'Customer.new.notes'.

so you have to do something like following

change `def self.called_this_month` to `def called_this_month`

OR

```
self.notes.where(:date => Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month).count
```

to

```
Customer.first.notes.where(:date => Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month).count
```

Answer (score 0):

`notes` is not a class method, it is an instance method. If you need a scope on `notes`, put it in the `Notes` model and use something like

```
def self.called_this_month
  where(:id => Notes.called_this_month.pluck(:customer_id).uniq)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Model:**

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
     def self.called_this_month(customer)
             customer.notes.where(:date => Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month).count
     end
 end
```

**Controller:**

```
@customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id])

//this will give you the count of the method call as output.
@count  = Customer.called_this_month(@customer)
```